# Problems creating HTML email from a file

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to send an HTML email via Python, argparse, and command line. Ideally I'd like to supply an HTML file that is read and transcribed into the body of the email but it seems all I've been able to do is attach the actual HTML file. I've omitted unnecessary code for an example.

```
def send_mail(args):
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    ...
    part2 = MIMEText(args.html, 'html')
    message.attach(part2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('html_file', help='The HTML file intended for use in the body of the email')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    args.html = open(args.html_file).read()

    send_mail(args)
```

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with `argparse` and everything to do with email creation. Look at [the example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html#id3).

Comment: I agree in part. That's how I have the email set up, but I'd like to be able to pass through an html file its self which is read and then written as the body. That's the part I've been unable to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future travelers, you have to ensure that

```
message = MIMEMultipart()
```

is actually

```
message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
```

otherwise it attaches the file instead of embedding it.